# Thinking-sphinx FATAL: failed to create binlog.001, error=Too many open files

Tags: sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I am using `Sphinx 2.2.11-id64-release` and `gem 'thinking-sphinx', '3.3.0'`.

`rake ts:configure`works fine and generated development development.sphinx.conf

But when running sphinx `rake ts:index ts:start` it fails and shows these errors in logs:

```
[Fri Dec 21 18:00:19.858 2018] [31823] WARNING: index 'section_not_today_1_with_text_89_idx_core': preload: failed to open /home/tyler/nmir/db/sphinx/development1/89/section_not_today_1_with_text_89_idx_core.spa: Too many open files; NOT SERVING
[Fri Dec 21 18:00:19.858 2018] [31823] WARNING: index 'section_today_0_with_text_address_89_idx_core': preload: failed to open /home/tyler/nmir/db/sphinx/development0/89/section_today_0_with_text_address_89_idx_core.spa: Too many open files; NOT SERVING
[Fri Dec 21 18:00:19.858 2018] [31823] WARNING: index 'section_not_today_0_with_text_address_89_idx_core': preload: failed to open /home/tyler/nmir/db/sphinx/development0/89/section_not_today_0_with_text_address_89_idx_core.spa: Too many open files; NOT SERVING
[Fri Dec 21 18:00:19.859 2018] [31823] WARNING: index 'section_today_1_with_text_address_89_idx_core': preload: failed to open /home/tyler/nmir/db/sphinx/development1/89/section_today_1_with_text_address_89_idx_core.spa: Too many open files; NOT SERVING
[Fri Dec 21 18:00:19.859 2018] [31823] WARNING: index 'section_not_today_1_with_text_address_89_idx_core': preload: failed to open /home/tyler/nmir/db/sphinx/development1/89/section_not_today_1_with_text_address_89_idx_core.spa: Too many open files; NOT SERVING
[Fri Dec 21 18:00:19.860 2018] [31823] WARNING: index 'section_today_0_with_text_90_idx_core': preload: failed to open /home/tyler/nmir/db/sphinx/development0/90/section_today_0_with_text_90_idx_core.spa: Too many open files; NOT SERVING
[Fri Dec 21 18:00:19.860 2018] [31823] WARNING: index 'section_not_today_0_with_text_90_idx_core': preload: failed to open /home/tyler/nmir/db/sphinx/development0/90/section_not_today_0_with_text_90_idx_core.spa: Too many open files; NOT SERVING
[Fri Dec 21 18:00:19.860 2018] [31823] WARNING: index 'section_today_1_with_text_90_idx_core': preload: failed to open /home/tyler/nmir/db/sphinx/development1/90/section_today_1_with_text_90_idx_core.spa: Too many open files; NOT SERVING
[Fri Dec 21 18:00:19.861 2018] [31823] WARNING: index 'section_not_today_1_with_text_90_idx_core': preload: failed to open /home/tyler/nmir/db/sphinx/development1/90/section_not_today_1_with_text_90_idx_core.spa: Too many open files; NOT SERVING
[Fri Dec 21 18:00:19.861 2018] [31823] WARNING: index 'section_today_0_with_text_address_90_idx_core': preload: failed to open /home/tyler/nmir/db/sphinx/development0/90/section_today_0_with_text_address_90_idx_core.spa: Too many open files; NOT SERVING
[Fri Dec 21 18:00:19.862 2018] [31823] WARNING: index 'section_not_today_0_with_text_address_90_idx_core': preload: failed to open /home/tyler/nmir/db/sphinx/development0/90/section_not_today_0_with_text_address_90_idx_core.spa: Too many open files; NOT SERVING
[Fri Dec 21 18:00:19.862 2018] [31823] WARNING: index 'section_today_1_with_text_address_90_idx_core': preload: failed to open /home/tyler/nmir/db/sphinx/development1/90/section_today_1_with_text_address_90_idx_core.spa: Too many open files; NOT SERVING
[Fri Dec 21 18:00:19.863 2018] [31823] WARNING: index 'section_not_today_1_with_text_address_90_idx_core': preload: failed to open /home/tyler/nmir/db/sphinx/development1/90/section_not_today_1_with_text_address_90_idx_core.spa: Too many open files; NOT SERVING
[Fri Dec 21 18:00:19.863 2018] [31823] WARNING: index 'section_today_0_with_text_91_idx_core': preload: failed to open /home/tyler/nmir/db/sphinx/development0/91/section_today_0_with_text_91_idx_core.spa: Too many open files; NOT SERVING
[Fri Dec 21 18:00:19.864 2018] [31823] WARNING: index 'section_not_today_0_with_text_91_idx_core': preload: failed to open /home/tyler/nmir/db/sphinx/development0/91/section_not_today_0_with_text_91_idx_core.spa: Too many open files; NOT SERVING
[Fri Dec 21 18:00:19.864 2018] [31823] WARNING: index 'section_today_1_with_text_91_idx_core': preload: failed to open /home/tyler/nmir/db/sphinx/development1/91/section_today_1_with_text_91_idx_core.spa: Too many open files; NOT SERVING
[Fri Dec 21 18:00:19.864 2018] [31823] WARNING: index 'section_not_today_1_with_text_91_idx_core': preload: failed to open /home/tyler/nmir/db/sphinx/development1/91/section_not_today_1_with_text_91_idx_core.spa: Too many open files; NOT SERVING
[Fri Dec 21 18:00:19.865 2018] [31823] WARNING: index 'section_today_0_with_text_address_91_idx_core': preload: failed to open /home/tyler/nmir/db/sphinx/development0/91/section_today_0_with_text_address_91_idx_core.spa: Too many open files; NOT SERVING
[Fri Dec 21 18:00:19.865 2018] [31823] WARNING: index 'section_not_today_0_with_text_address_91_idx_core': preload: failed to open /home/tyler/nmir/db/sphinx/development0/91/section_not_today_0_with_text_address_91_idx_core.spa: Too many open files; NOT SERVING
[Fri Dec 21 18:00:19.865 2018] [31823] WARNING: index 'section_today_1_with_text_address_91_idx_core': preload: failed to open /home/tyler/nmir/db/sphinx/development1/91/section_today_1_with_text_address_91_idx_core.spa: Too many open files; NOT SERVING
[Fri Dec 21 18:00:19.866 2018] [31823] WARNING: index 'section_not_today_1_with_text_address_91_idx_core': preload: failed to open /home/tyler/nmir/db/sphinx/development1/91/section_not_today_1_with_text_address_91_idx_core.spa: Too many open files; NOT SERVING
[Fri Dec 21 18:00:19.868 2018] [31823] FATAL: failed to create /home/tyler/nmir/tmp/binlog/development/binlog.001: errno=24, error=Too many open files
[Fri Dec 21 18:00:19.915 2018] [31822] watchdog: main process 31823 exited cleanly (exit code 1), shutting down
```

Comment: The 'open files limit' is generally configured at the OS level, eg for centos https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-increase-the-maximum-number-of-open-files/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this issue by adding the following line to both `/etc/systemd/system.conf` and `/etc/systemd/user.conf`

```
DefaultLimitNOFILE=65000
```

Answer (score 1):

As @barryhunter has noted, the issue here is the number of files that you're allowed to open at an operating system level. You're hitting this because of the large number of Sphinx indices you've got defined - but there should be ways around it - perhaps by using `ulimit`, as Barry's linked to in the comment.